# Why maven jenkins build added javac.batch file into build?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm facing problems while taking maven project build from jenkins.
When I take build locally it's working fine, but when I take build from jenkins it adds **javac.batch** and one more file name like **org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler3395975603072130649arguments**

What are the probable cause of this and solution to remove or prevent addition this file's into build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding on web i got the reason why it is happening. It is bug in maven compiler plugin.
**When you compile a java project with -X maven option and true in the maven-compiler-plugin configuration, the following extra files are written to target\classes and bundled in the root directory of the jar:
javac.bat
org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler8515975925044691799arguments**

for detail explanation see [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-225)